# extract content using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sentence: `enum('active','disabled','deleted')`. What I would like is an array with:

```
array(
    [0]=>'active',
    [1]=>'disabled',
    [2]=>'deleted'
)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are the quotes supposed to be included in the match results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this regex should work given your string.

```
$sentence = "enum('active','disabled','deleted')";
preg_match_all("/'([^']*)'/", $sentence, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The above code outputs the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => active
    [1] => disabled
    [2] => deleted
)
```

Regex explained.

```
'               //Match opening quote.
    (           //Start capture.
        [^']*   //Match any characters but the end quote.
    )           //End capture.
'               //Match closing quote.
```

**UPDATE:**

A commenter suggested that perhaps you are looking to keep the quotes. If that is the case, the following regex will work.

```
$s = "enum('active','disabled','deleted')";
preg_match_all("/('[^']*')/", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'active'
    [1] => 'disabled'
    [2] => 'deleted'
)
```

Regex explained.

```
(               //Start capture.
    '           //Match opening quote.
        [^']*   //Match any characters but the end quote.
    '           //Match closing quote.
)               //End capture.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
'(\w+?)'
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qO4oF9/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [6-12]  `active`
MATCH 2
1.  [15-23] `disabled`
MATCH 3
1.  [26-33] `deleted`
```